# PyQt: How to create a custom QAction with custom events

Tags: python, events, pyqt, pyside, signals-slots

I try to add mouse events to a new QAction object. I want to use them in custom menu's.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import QEvent, pyqtSignal as Signal, pyqtSlot as Slot

class MouseEvent(QEvent):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MouseEvent,self).__init__(QEvent.Type(QEvent.MouseButtonRelease))

class MyAction(QtGui.QAction):
    clicked = Signal()

    def __init__(self, name, parent):
        super(MyAction, self).__init__(name, parent)
        self.customEvent(MouseEvent)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            event.accept()
            self.clicked.emit()
            self.rightClicked(event)
        else:
            event.ignore()

    @Slot()
    def rightClicked(self, event):
        print "right clicked"
        return event

class AnyApplication(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AnyApplication, self).__init__()
        self.UI()

    def UI(self):
        menuBar = self.menuBar()
        m = menuBar.addMenu("Edit")
        a = MyAction("Do", m)
        #a.clicked.connect(self.doMoreWithClicked)
        m.addAction(a)

    def doMorWithClicked(self):
        print "Do more.."

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
anyApp = AnyApplication()
anyApp.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    self.event(MouseEvent)
TypeError: QAction.event(QEvent): argument 1 has unexpected type   'PyQt4.QtCore.pyqtWrapperType'
```

I really want to understand how I create my own events and combine them with signals and slots.

Thanks...